# How to remap shift-space to underscore in linux (not GNOME or KDE)

Tags: linux, keyboard

I do a lot of shell scripting in linux (running xmonad window manager, so I can use xmodmap or xinput, but not GNOME or KDE control panels), and it would be *super* useful for a shift-space keystroke to output an underscore ("_") character.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following xmodmap expression will map Shift+Space to underscore. Add this to `~/.Xmodmaprc` and run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmaprc` during startup to make it persistent.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 65 = space underscore space'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you been through keymap, loadkeys, etc - http://linux.die.net/man/5/keymaps .  It's the same idea but for the kernel and the keyboard driver.  You should be able to take your present layout and just add a couple of lines.